# Finding the space $A_{\infty}$ lying inside the infinite product.

Tags: general-topology

Continuing speaking about inverse limits.

Here is the question:

> [image]
>   [image]

Could anyone help me in solving it, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f_{n+1}(a_{n+1})=a_n$ for all $n$, just using the definition of the projections and applying to $\bar{a}$

Hence the definition of $A_\infty := \{ \bar{a} \in \prod_n A_n: f_{n+1}(a_{n+1})=a_n \}$

The fact that all possible triangles commute from the neighbouring ones that commute is because the $f_n$ themselves form an inverse system, check that yourself.

Comment: How can we check the $f_{n}$ form an inverse system?

Comment: @Mathstupid that’s obvious.

Comment: it is not obvious for me.

Comment: @Mathstupid The $f_n$ are given maps on the spaces $A_n$ such that they form an inverse system. That's given beforehand. The exercise defines the subset of the product that will be an inverse limit for the inverse system.