# Finding the space $A_{\infty}$ lying inside the infinite product.(2)

Tags: general-topology

As a completion of this question here [Finding the space $A_{\infty}$ lying inside the infinite product.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3621689/finding-the-space-a-infty-lying-inside-the-infinite-product) I have the following question:

> [image]

Could anyone help me in proving so please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check the condition for being an inverse limit, we need to consider a space $W$ and a family of maps $w_n: W \to A_n$ such that $f_{n+1} \circ w_{n+1} = w_n$ for all $n$, so the $w_n$ respect the bonding maps. We then need to define a unique $w: W \to A_\infty$ such that $\pi_n \circ w = w_n$ for all $n$.

Define $w$ on $\bar{a}=(a_n)_n \in \prod_n A_n$ by $w(x)=(w_n(x))_n$ for $x \in W$.

The "respecting conditions" imply that $w(x) \in A_\infty$ and also that $\pi_n \circ w=w_n$. Unicity is also immediate from these last conditions (and by how products are defined). We have no choice.

Continuity of $w$ follows from those same conditions, as all $w_n$ are continuous.